# Calculate distance by comparing different points

Tags: python-2.7

I have different locations, and I need to calculate the distance between them:

```
Location      Lat     Long     Distance
   A         -20      -50      (A-B)+(A-C)+(A-D)
   B         -20.3    -51      (B-A)+(B-C)+(B-D)
   C         -21      -50      (C-A)+(C-B)+(C-D)
   D         -20.8    -50.2    (D-A)+(D-B)+(D-C)
```

Would anyone know me?

I'm using this equation to calculate the distance between two points, but I don't know how to calculate between several points.

```
R = 6373.0
dist_lat=lat2-lat
dist_lon=long2-lon

a= np.sin(dist_lat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dist_lon/2)**2
b= 2 * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(a), np.sqrt(1 - a))
Dist= R * b
```

Comment: usually distance is a metric between 2 points, what do you mean by "distance between several points" ?

Comment: I need to calculate a distance between each point, and sum. I need to calculate a distance, for example,  A in relation to B, C, D and sum as distances.

Comment: so for /every/ distinct combination of 2 (or more?) points you need the distance in between them, and then you want the sum all the distances ? (ah, now your Distance-Column makes sense)

Comment: Yes, right! I need to calculate distance of each point in relation other points, and sum the difference.

Answer (score 0):

this is my first time with python so beware, also I made this rather quickly - it is probably buggy.

Tested on python2.7.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

# these are the points
points = {
    'A' :{'lat':-20   ,'lon':-50}  
    ,'B':{'lat':-20.3 ,'lon':-51}  
    ,'C':{'lat':-21   ,'lon':-50}  
    ,'D':{'lat':-20.8 ,'lon':-50.2}  
}

# this calculates the distance beween two points
# basicly your formula wrapped in a function
# - used below
def distance(a, b):
    R = 6373.0
    dist_lat = a['lat']-b['lat']
    dist_lon = a['lon']-b['lon']

    x = np.sin(dist_lat/2)**2 + np.cos(b['lat']) * np.cos(a['lat']) * np.sin(dist_lon/2)**2
    y = 2 * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(x), np.sqrt(1 - x))
    return R * y


distances = {}

# produce the distance beween all combinations
# see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html
# - uses above function
for x in it.combinations(points.keys(), 2):
    distances[ ''.join(x) ] = distance(points[x[0]],points[x[1]])

# for every starting point 
# - filter the distance it is involved in
# - sum
for CH in ('A','B','C','D'):
    print CH,' ', sum(dict((key,value) for key, value in distances.iteritems() if CH in key).values())
```

output:

```
$ python2.7 test.py
A   6983.4634697
B   9375.21128818
C   5859.5650322
D   9472.23979008
```